# Repeatedly match a perl expression for a specific/multiple number of times?

Tags: regex, perl, match, repeat

For the given string example: `<a><b><c><d><e><f><g>`
I'd like to write an expression that will repeatedly match the first 5 `<(?)>` tokens and put them in $1, $2, $3, $4 and $5.

The naive implementation would be of course: `/<(?)><(?)><(?)><(?)><(?)>/`

But back in the day I remember doing something like `/(<(?)>:5)/` instead.

I'm having a hard time finding this syntax.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
perl -wE '$_="<a><b><c><d><e><f><g>"; say /<(.)>/g;'
```

Will give all the matches. It's just a matter of getting a slice:

```
my @tokens = (/<(.)>/g)[0 .. 4];
```